# Taking unlocked iPhone 4 to Canada?

Tags: iphone

I am visiting Canada (Vancouver, BC) this coming week from the UK and have an unlocked iPhone 4 (bought SIM-free from Apple).

What are the best options for buying a pre-paid SIM that will give me some data (around 500Mb) whilst I'm away?

I already had a SIM cutting tool to make micro-SIM cards from standard SIM cards.

Jack

Answer (score 2):

Vancouver is the home territory of Telus, so they're probably your best bet. All three of our major carriers (Rogers, Telus and Bell) support GSM *and* carry the iPhone 4, so you should be fine.

The only Telus pre-paid data plan in BC appears to be $20 for 250MB, http://www.telusmobility.com/en/BC/prepaid/rates.shtml

Rogers has a $45/month pre-paid, includes 500MB, that looks decent, http://www.rogers.com/web/content/wireless-products/plans

Answer (score 0):

I have heard Rogers and Telus are good but I have never been to CA and I am unfamiliar with their plans. With all wireless coverage it all depends on the area. I would recommend talking with someone when you get there and finding out what is good in the area you are going to be visiting.